# Creating a random make matrix with a particular rank

Tags: linear-algebra

Does Mathematica have a built-in function that will return a random mxn matrix with rank r?l

Comment: No, but trivial to build fn. to do so...

Comment: Create an $r \times r$ rank-$r$ matrix, then pad each column with $m-r$ with the same random values (thus preserving the rank of the matrix).  Then create $n-r$ column vectors by a random linear combination of the $r$ basis vectors.  You can randomly permute columns or make new linear combinations, to "scramble" the matrix without changing its rank $r$.

Comment: I did this: r = 0;
While[r != 3, A = RandomInteger[5, {4, 5}]; r = MatrixRank[A]], but I will check out your answer as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### For square matrices:

You can try this:

```
RandomMatrix[rank_, m_] := 
  Sum[TensorProduct @@ RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {2, m}], {i, rank}];
```

It returns a pseudorandom `m`-by-`m` matrix with rank `rank`.

Example usage:

```
MatrixRank@RandomMatrix[5, 10]
(*5*)
```

#### Rectangular matrices

For rectangular matrices, try this:

```
RandomMatrix[rank_, m_, n_] := 
  Sum[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, m]\[TensorProduct]RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 
     n], {i, rank}];
```

Example usage:

```
Dimensions[RandomMatrix[3, 4, 5]]
MatrixRank[RandomMatrix[3, 4, 5]]
(*{4, 5}*)
(*3*)
```