# create a rank 1 matrix from two vectors

Tags: matrix, random

I've seen the answers [1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/158173/construct-matrix-from-vectors) and [2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/77441/creating-a-random-make-matrix-with-a-particular-rank) about the transposition and creation of rank $m$ matrices.

What I'd like to do is first create a random vector, which I know how to do with

`d = 3;`

`a = RandomReal[{-3, 3}, {d}]`

and then create the matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix} a_1\\a_1\\a_3\end{pmatrix}\cdot(1,1,1)=\begin{pmatrix}a_1&a_1&a_1\\
a_2&a_2&a_2\\
a_3&a_3&a_3\end{pmatrix}$

But `MatrixForm[a.Transpose[{1, 1, 1}]]` doesn't work.

Edit:

I randomly ran the line `TensorProduct[a, {1, 1, 1}]` and that works (didn't expect to find an answer like that)

Answer (score 5):

That's precisely what a [`KroneckerProduct`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KroneckerProduct.html) is:

```
KroneckerProduct[{a1, a2, a3}, {1, 1, 1}]
(*    {{a1, a1, a1}, {a2, a2, a2}, {a3, a3, a3}}    *)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have already answered your question. I only give  two other solutions that came first into head:

```
 d = 3;
        a = RandomReal[{-3, 3}, {d}];
    a /. {x_, y_, z_} -> {{x, x, x}, {y, y, y}, {z, z, z}}

    (* {{1.62507, 1.62507, 1.62507}, {2.03748, 2.03748, 
      2.03748}, {-0.478757, -0.478757, -0.478757}}  *)
```

and

```
Map[Times[#, {1, 1, 1}] &, a]
    (* {{1.62507, 1.62507, 1.62507}, {2.03748, 2.03748, 
      2.03748}, {-0.478757, -0.478757, -0.478757}} *)
```

Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

The operation you are looking for with your two vectors is the outer product. Hence:

```
a = RandomReal[{-3, 3}, 3];
b = RandomReal[{-3, 3}, 3];
Outer[Times, a, b]
```

gives the matrix.