# Creating a random symmetric matrix with a particular rank

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, random, constraint, symmetry

The documentation about [LinearAlgebra](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/LinearAlgebra.html#10712) has a section on *Constructing Matrices*, but the examples of random matrices using [`RandomReal`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomReal.html) don't offer an obvios way to impose symmetry or rank.

There is a similar question ([77441](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/77441/10397)) asking for a matrix with a particular rank, but doesn't address the *symmetry* constraint.

**Is there any way to create a $n \times n$ random symmetric matrix with a specified [`MatrixRank`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatrixRank.html) $r$?**

i.e. A $6 \times 6$ random symmetric matrix with rank $3$.

Comment: @rhermans gave a wonderful answer, but it cannot hurt to have a second way of doing it: I suggest this `symm[n_] := Module[{mm = RandomReal[10, {n, n}]}, (mm + Transpose[mm])/2]` which creates a symmetric random matrix. Then I remembered the strongly related to the OP [**`answer`**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/77441/creating-a-random-make-matrix-with-a-particular-rank) which constructs a random matrix of specific rank. Combining the above should do the trick, but I am stupid and I have not managed that yet

Comment: And to expand a bit, using the above pieces of information the naive `RandomMatrix[rank_, m_] := Sum[TensorProduct@symm[m], {i, rank}]` fails and likewise for `RandomMatrix[rank_, m_] := Sum[TensorProduct /@ symm[m], {i, rank}]` as the rank becomes 6 instead of 3

Comment: @lotus2019 I tried to improve your question to show the minimum diligence one could expect: a search on the documentation and  a search on the site (with links) and an explanation why neither was enough to answer your particular problem. Also improved the formatting, the *tags* and made explicit the need to check for `MatrixRank`. Next time you should do that or more, not less.

Comment: @rhermans Thank you for your excellent answer. I have searched this website before ask this question, and found the answer to create a random matrix with a specific rank, and the answer to create a random symmetric matrix, but it has little to do with this question. I also considered creating a random symmetric matrix first, and then reducing the rank of the random symmetric matrix by replacing some rows and columns, but this method is not elegant. Next time, I will put these efforts into the question for reference. Thank you for your kindly advice and editing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Documentation

There is a [`ResourceFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ResourceFunction.html) called[`RandomMatrix`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/RandomMatrix/) contributed by *Dennis M Schneider*.

The documentation reads

> For matrices of kind "`Idempotent"`,`"Symmetric"`, `"SymmetricIdempotent"`
> or `"Hermitian"`, setting the option `"Rank" → k` will choose a matrix of
> that kind having rank $k$.

## Matrix

```
m = ResourceFunction["RandomMatrix"][
    "Symmetric"
    , Real
    , {-1,1}
    , {6,6}
    , "Rank"->3
]
```

[image]

## Tests

```
Rule[ #, #[m] ]& /@ {
  MatrixQ,
  SquareMatrixQ,
  Dimensions,
  MatrixRank,
  SymmetricMatrixQ,
  DiagonalizableMatrixQ,
  HermitianMatrixQ,
  NormalMatrixQ,
  PositiveSemidefiniteMatrixQ
} // TableForm
```

[image]

Comment: This is very slick!